# EF 4.3+ How to get current database initialzer

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I get the current database initializer, so I can test that the right one is set before automatic publish?

**Edit**: I want to create a test case that is testing if a team member forgot to remove a line like this:

```
Database.SetInitializer<SomeModel>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SomeModel>());
```

but there is no method or property like Database.GetInitializer().

is there a way to get current database initializer?

Comment: Can you post a code sample, which will set db initializer outside of your dbcontext code?

Comment: Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SomeModel>());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going about this wrong, if you're relying on developers to remember to commit or not to commit a line.

You should consider decoupling the initialization from the code by setting it in the web.config or app.config. Using web.config transformations or [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) for app.config, you would have a transformation per configuration, e.g. Debug, Test, Production.

In the Web.Debug.Config, you would then specify which initializer to use for that configuration:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <contexts>
      <context type="Company.Product.Infrastructure.BoundedContext, Company.Product.Infrastructure" disableDatabaseInitialization="false" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <databaseInitializer type="Company.Product.Infrastructure.DatabaseInitializers.DebugDatabaseInitializer, Company.Product.Infrastructure" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
  </entityFramework>
```

For the other configurations, you would replace the `//entityFramework/contexts/context/databaseInitializer/@type` in the above configuration to use another database initializer. This would allow you to use DropCreateDatabaseAlways for Debug, DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges for Test and disable initialization for Production.

As a test, I tried adding database initialization both in the code and in the .config and the .config takes precedence.

Comment: I believe your example is missing the transformation attributes required for this to work properly. See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(VS.100).aspx (Unless it's me that's missing something!)

Comment: You are correct. I missed it when writing the answer. I edited the answer to include transformation and upvoted your comment.