# How to seperate Initializer method for various environments

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, web-deployment

I am new to EF Code first.

I've project in which i've created Initializer class which is derived from CreateDatabaseIfNotExists, DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges, DropCreateDatabaseAlways Or Custom DB Initializer.

I've used "DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges" for development purpose, It's recreate database whenever model changes and it's help during development, but now time to deploy to QA and eventually production environment.

My idea is to keep this for Development

```
namespace Models
{
    public class SchoolInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SchoolContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(SchoolContext context)
        {
        }
    }
 }
```

and for QA or Production

```
namespace Models
{
    public class SchoolInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<SchoolContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(SchoolContext context)
        {
        }
    }
 }
```

How to achive this using app.config file. So when i pubish for QA or Release, it should change automatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SlowCheetah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) package, which enables you to transform your app.config.

For an example of how to do the transformations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13203775/441292

Comment: Why i need slowCheetah when I can publish using visual studio without slowcheetha, like what i did for connection string using configuration Manager.

I can't  upload picture here..

Comment: If publishing a project dependent on app.config, you need SlowCheetah to perform the transformations as Visual Studio only supports web.config transformations. Microsoft is working on adding similar support in VS2015, http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2043217-support-web-config-style-transforms-on-any-file-in. In VS2013, right-clicking an app.config and selecting Add Transform will actually include SlowCheetah automagically.

Comment: Ok, Can you show me how to achive above usng app.config. I would learn about slowcheeta later.
What changs i've to make so that instead of writtin in Model namespace, it can look in app.config please.
Thank you.

Comment: I linked to an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933661/ef-4-3-how-to-get-current-database-initialzer/13203775#13203775) in the original answer.